# Cannot send the data from main process to render in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ipc

I am beginner to Electron, and I am developing an educational game. When the user clicks the start button, I want the main process to fetch information from the storage folder (I am ok with data being open to users). The main process accomplishes that without a problem.

main.js

```
ipcMain.on('load-sets', (event) => {
  const directoriesInDIrectory = fs.readdirSync(folderName, { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter((item) => item.isDirectory())
    .map((item) => item.name);
    event.sender.send("loaded-sets", directoriesInDIrectory);
})
```

Then, I use ipcRenderer in preload.js to receive the message.

preload.js

```
ipcRenderer.on("loaded-sets", (event, package) => {
    window.loaded_sets = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < package.length; i++) {

        window.loaded_sets[i] = package[i];
    }
})
```

Finally, I expose the sets via contextBridge:

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
    LoadFiles,
    quit,
    sets: () => window.loaded_sets,
    sentToRender,
})
```

However, when I run the following code in render.js:
`console.log(window.api.sets())`

it outputs undefined.

I've already tried using postMessage and eventListeners associated with it. Also, I've tried to get the variable via another function:

```
function sentToRender() {
    return window.loaded_sets;
```

The function was also exposed and could be called in the renderer process. Yet, the output was still undefined.

---

For those wondering why I won't send the data straight to the renderer, the renderer returns error when I try require ipcRenderer and I heard that it is a good practice to navigate data through preload. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In main.js

```
    ipcMain.on('load-sets', (event) => {
      const directoriesInDIrectory = fs.readdirSync(folderName, { 
    withFileTypes: true })
    `enter code here`.filter((item) => item.isDirectory())
    .map((item) => item.name);
  event.sender.send("loaded-sets", directoriesInDIrectory);
})
```

### In preload.js

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", (package)=> ipcRenderer.on("loaded-sets", (package)))
```

### In renderer.js

```
window.api((event, package) => {
        window.loaded_sets = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < package.length; i++) {
    
            window.loaded_sets[i] = package[i];
           
        }
        console.log(window.loaded_sets)
       
    })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add event emitting from renderer process if it’s wasn’t done.

```
ipcRenderer.send(“load-sets”);
```

To make the function work on main process side.

But if you don’t want to send the event from renderer process, then remove ipcMain listener and just send the event by doing

```
yourRenderedWindow.webContents.send("loaded-sets", directoriesInDIrectory);
```

Comment: the function works on the main process side. the thing is that I cannot send the data back to the renderer through preload

Comment: Try using webContents.send in place of event.sender